# Docker create base image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to create a docker base image from scratch. The Dockerfile is simple:

```
FROM scratch
COPY data_folder  /opt/data_folder/
CMD ["/opt/data_folder/"]
```

However, at the final Dockerfile instruction when the default command is run the process exits and says that "oci runtime error: exec: "/opt/data_folder/": permission denied". 
Why is this happening since the docker docs specify that this is how you create a base image.

**Note:** I am using docker on windows native.
**Note:** The Dockerfile is run from docker-compose up.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by `CMD ["/opt/data_folder/"]`? Is it that to check if directory present?

Comment: Hello and sorry for the late response. I was in a rush and did not pay attention that in fact "hello" represented an executable. I thought it was a folder. Sorry, for the obvious mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to "execute" a folder `/opt/data_folder/`

The [docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/) suggest executing a command (the *executable* `hello`)

```
FROM scratch
ADD hello /
CMD ["/hello"]
```

Comment: This results error: `docker: Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"/hello\\\": stat /hello: no such file or directory\"\n".`

Comment: @Rao did you have a `hello` executable file in your Dockerfile context (meaning on your disk, where the Dockerfile is) called `hello`, to copy (ADD) to your image?

Comment: @VnoC, Looking at OP, he was adding a directory, not a file or an executable. Of course, it was not clear why he was running directory command which I requested him for clarification. And thank you for your time looking at the comments.

Comment: @Rao yes, the all point of the answer is to provide an example that would make sense: copy of an executable, and reference of that executable as the default CMD. The OP copied a folder (why not), but try to execute a folder (which won't work)